How in eclipse import add-exports
In Eclipse there is possibility to add exports for JVM via it's GUI(as on pic attached), but after reopening project or switching between branches the added items disapears. Is there any way to prepare list of needed exports and import them at once?

That all goes in the .classpath file in the project. It should stay unchanged unless your switch branch is overwriting it.

@greg-449 Indeed I saw these parameters are placed into .classpath, the problem is when I manually modify .classpath of newly created project and opens it then they are mot appears in this window
